# PyCharm run configurations not on main window

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-ide

PyCharm Community Edition as shown below on Ubuntu 18.04 box.

[image]

Notice the run configurations dropdown is not on my main window

[image]

Searched docs/settings/views and can't figure out how to get it attached to the main view. Anyone else have this issue?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks @LazyOne, your answer brought my attention to the navigation bar; however, when I enabled it as you suggested it was still hidden.  This seems to be a known issue in [IntelliJ](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205816239-How-do-I-restore-the-main-toolbar-) with a known solution.  I had to edit the PyCharm config file `~/.PyCharmCE2019.3/config/options/ui.lnf.xml`, changing the following line then restarting the IDE:

```
<application>
  <component name="UISettings">
    ...
    <option name="SHOW_MAIN_MENU" value="true" />
    ...
  </component>
</application>
```

Somehow it got set to false...

## LazyOne's original answer below

**Main Menu | View | Appearance**.

Either enable **Navigation Bar** to see file path navigation + small toolbar on the right ... or **Toolbar** to see a full toolbar (overkill as for me as you would barely use that many icons there).

[image]

A drop down with Run/Debug Configurations is part of both toolbars by default (full and small).

If you need to customize them -- `Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | Menus and Toolbars`:

[image]

*P.S. Screenshots are from PhpStorm, but it should be the same for PyCharm (as they both based on IDEA platform).*

Answer (score 3):

@LazyOne has the correct answer if you installed PyCharm from source. If you installed it as a snap package, there is no `~/.PyCharm*` dir.

Instead, you'll need to edit `~/.config/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.1/options/ui.lnf.xml`

(where the `CE2020.1` part is the version you have installed)

Answer (score 0):

Had the dame issue, I thought it was a Mac issue at first, Just to let you guys know that they have added a setting for this.
Settings > Appearance & Behavior > New UI (Beta) > Enable new UI
[Enable_new_UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsfvJ.png)

Unchecking the "Enable new UI" setting should bring it back to look like the 2022 version