# PyCharm Navigation not showing

Tags: pycharm

I'm using PyCharm on Mac. It was about a week ago since the last time I opened it and when I did I couldn't find the navigation anymore, and it's showing only this:

[image]

I went to Preferences > Menu and Toolbars but still nothing. This is the version I'm using now:

[image]

Comment: `and it's showing only this:`. Is that all it shows, you dont see the IDE? Or are you on about the `navigation `section in the menu bar?

Comment: The IDE's open when I took a screenshot, even had it on full screen, and it's still not showing the other menus :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Main Menu | View | Appearance**.

Either enable **Navigation Bar** to see file path navigation + small toolbar on the right ... or **Toolbar** to see a full toolbar (overkill as for me as you would barely use that many icons there).

[image]

A drop down with Run/Debug Configurations is part of both toolbars by default (full and small).

If you need to customize them -- `Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | Menus and Toolbars`:

[image]

*P.S. Screenshots are from PhpStorm, but it should be the same for PyCharm (as they both based on IDEA platform).*

**This answer is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60619618/pycharm-run-configurations-not-on-main-window)**