# Missing toolbar in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

This sounds like a duplicate post but I tried to find answers to this question online and can't seem to find any helpful information...

I opened several downloaded class files that form one project, and can't seem to run the code. There is no toolbar with the run and debug button and the shortcut (^R) is not working. Right-clicking on the files neither gives the option to execute the code.

[image: window]

[image: closeup]

[image: closeup1]

[image: closeup2]

Comment: [Show Main Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60623281/14353101) - Stackoverflow Found a similar thread, try this :)

Comment: In the screenshot you attached I don't see a main method. There should be a public static void main(String[] args) method that starts the application. In order to execute the thread run method you can have a look at: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html

Comment: Seems to me that you are in the Light Edit mode where it is just an editor. Switch to the full IDE mode. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/lightedit-mode.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your screenshots (especially #2, the one that show the `File` menu) it seems to me that you are in the **Light Edit mode** where the whole IDE pretty much is just an editor.

Switch to the full IDE mode (where you open the actual project) and you will have the full functionality.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/lightedit-mode.html